# reactjs if/else inside object.keys

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In react, I am trying to have if/else statement inside object.keys . Is it possible? Following code gives compilation errors. Thanks

```
    Object.keys(processItem).forEach(key =>
        if(processItem[key] !== 0) {
            !Boolean(processItem[key])   ? delete processItem[key] : '';                    
        }
    );
```

Comment: This is not a react question btw, this is just a javascript question. In JS, you have to wrap your arrow function body with curly brackets in order to use multiple statements inside the function.

Answer (score 3):

Yes - you just need to wrap it in {}

```
  Object.keys(processItem).forEach(key =>
   { if(processItem[key] !== 0) {
        !Boolean(processItem[key])   ? delete processItem[key] : '';                    
    }}
);
```

Comment: I get this error when i replace with your above code. '  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions'